# How to keep the first rows NaN while using xlsread

Tags: matlab, csv, nan, xls

Matlab deletes all first rows NaN when I use xlsread, do you know if there's any way to keep them?

Thank you

Comment: Try the third output of `xlsread` i.e. `[~,~,all] = xlsread(....)`. The first output only stores numbers. You'll have to extract the numbers from `all` yourself replacing the rest (I'm assuming a first row of headers) with `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Read the contents of the file into the third output of `xlsread`.

```
[num,text,raw] = xlsread()
```

The contents of 'raw' should have what you're asking for.